# CSS while hover a div how to display other class(or) div?

Tags: css, css-transitions

this is my sample stylesheet

```
 <style>  
 .cover{ margin 0 auto;}    
  .cover .ab{ display:inline-block color:#000; height:25px;}
```

while hover the class .ab class .ac should drop from -25px from 0px

```
  .cover .ab:hover .ac{ top:0px }  
  .ac{ position:absolute; top:-25px; height:25px;} 
   </style>
```

my html looks like

```
      <body>
       <div class="cover">
       <div class="ab">&nbsp;</div>
       </div>
       <div class="ac">&nbsp;</div>
       </body>
```

it doesn't seems to works is there anything wrong in statement please help me thanks n advance.

Comment: you can't do this with CSS unless `.ac` is a child of `.ab`, try jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.cover .ab:hover .ac { top:0px }
```

This is not working since .ac is not a child of .ab (and also not a child of .cover by the way).

Answer (score 2):

Use Sibling selector over Cover. <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMs74/)</kbd>

```
  .cover:hover ~ .ac { top:0px }
```

Comment: Thanks dude PSCoder..got some idea.. :)

Comment: :) you can rearrange your html to use adjascent sibling selector or sibling selector.. At thi spoint till css3 what you are looking for is not possible. You might event want to use JS/jquery if you want to acheive that without changing your html.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it if both of your divs are siblings:

```
<div class="cover">
   <div class="ab">asdfa</div>     
   <div class="ac">test</div>
</div>
```

then css:

```
.ab:hover ~ .ac{ top:0px;height:25px; }
```

would work for you [working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/4p8CM/1220/).

The [general sibling combinator](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector) (`~`) works for siblings.

you can move your `.ac` div in `.cover` div or apply css on `.cover` div:

```
.cover:hover ~ .ac { top:0px }
```