# Make a element visible when another element is hovered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make text appear below an image when it is being hovered upon, but can't get the syntax right. I'm beginning to learn CSS, so I may not be following the best practices, please point out how I can solve my problem better!

```
<div class="X">
    <span class="Y">
        <a href="XYZ">
            <span class="A"></span>
        </a>
        <span class="A-element">A</span>
    </span>
    <span class="Y">
        <a href="XYZ">
            <span class="B"></span>
        </a>
        <span class="B-element">B</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```css
.X { 
  font-size: 5em;
}

.Y {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.A-element {
  display: none;
}

.B-element {
  display: none;
}

.A {
  color: #fff;
}

.B {
  color: #fff;
}

.A:hover .A-element {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
}

.B:hover .B-element {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Your markup has no `img` elements...

Comment: Considering the given markup, It is NOT possible to target `.*-element` by `.*:hover`. (ps: `*` = `A` or `B`).

Comment: Oops, I meant span object A, B, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749378/making-an-element-visible-by-hovering-another-element-without-hover-property

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS while hover a div how to display other class(or) div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140744/css-while-hover-a-div-how-to-display-other-classor-div)

Answer (score 1):

Hovering over `.A` to change the style of `.A-element` isn't possible with CSS because to do this we'd have to first select the parent of `.A`, and CSS has no parent selector.

What is possible, however, is to instead place the hover on the `a` element within your `.Y` element, and use the [`+` adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) to select the element next to it:

```css
.Y a:hover + span + span {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
}
```

As you can see, I haven't had to use the `.A-element` or `.B-element` classes at all as this will apply to both your `.A-element` and `.B-element` elements.

---

### Simplified Code Snippet

```css
.Y a:hover + span {
  background: tomato;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="X">
    <span class="Y">
        <a href="XYZ">
            <span class="A">Hover here</span>
        </a>
        <span class="A-element">A</span>
    </span>
    <span class="Y">
        <a href="XYZ">
            <span class="B">Hover here</span>
        </a>
        <span class="B-element">B</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The above code works, but it's messing up the positioning of elements on my webpage. Is there any way to "reserve" a space below `Hover here` for `A` so that things don't move around?

Comment: @user3666471 you could set a `margin-bottom` and then remove it when your element is hovered.

Comment: @user3666471 - you could also make it a feature with a transition, depending on what you are trying to achieve. [Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/gotuf/1/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1):

you can use hover on parent element. for example

```
.Y:hover .A-element {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
}
```